# Efeito mouseover para espalhar icones/imagens sobrepostas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,
no sistema em que estou trabalhando existem alguns icones/imagens (que são div's) que as vezes ficam sobrepostas.
Este é o funcionamento correto delas, elas atualizam suas posições automaticamente e as vezes ficam uma sobre a outra, porém está sendo necessário criar uma funcionalidade no sistema para que ao colocar o mouse sobre as imagens sobrepostas, elas se espalhem (tipo uma explosão), que poderia ser em forma circular em torno no ponteiro do mouse.
Tentei fazer com jQuery usando o método animate e com JavaScript usando offset mas ainda não obtive sucesso.
Se alguém tiver alguma dica serei imensamente grato.

var img = $(document.createElement('div')).attr({ class: 'icon' }).css('left', left);

```
                $(img).mouseover(function () {
                    $(img).animate({ "top": "-=10px", "left": "+=10px" }, "slow");
                });
                $(img).mouseout(function () {
                    $(img).animate({ "left": "-=10px", "top": "+=10px" }, "slow");
                });
```

Comment: Você poderia fornecer algum trecho do codigo que tentou, talvez no JSFiddle?

Comment: Olá Rhuan! Podes juntar o HTML para completar a pergunta? e quantos elementos são? numero variável?

Comment: editei a pergunta com um trecho do que eu já tentei fazer, se precisarem de mais informações é só perguntar.
No caso esse trecho de código está dentro de um each, para varrer o array de todas as imagens.